# Proving an implication

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $x, y, n \in \mathbb N $ where $ x,y \gt 1$ and $2^n + 1 = xy$. Let $a \in \mathbb N.$

Prove:

a)
$ 2^a \mid(x-1) \Rightarrow a< n$

b) 
$ 2^a \mid(x-1) ↔ 2^a \mid(y-1)$

For a) I have: For some $s \in \mathbb Z$, $x-1 = s 2^a$.

and b) I tried to substitute $x=$ $2^n+1\over y$ into the LHS of the statement.

Now I am not sure how to continue with this proof. Any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

For (a), it follows immediately from the fact that $y > 1$, so $2^n > x$.

For (b), notice that

$$2^n + 1 - y = xy - y = (x - 1)y = 2^a w y$$

for some integer $w$, whenever $2^a | (x - 1)$. You should be able to rearrange this into an expression of the form $y = 2^a$(integer), recalling that from part (a) it is true that $a < n$.